# Ajax Cart showing configurable product image instead of simple product

Tags: magento-1, ajaxaddtocart

I am using ajax cart and minicart shows configurable image instead of simple image.

Already Set Product Thumbnail in

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart -> Configurable Product Image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code after `Add to cart` controller and its working fine.

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quoteId = $session->getQuote()->getId();
$session->clear();
$session->setQuoteId($quoteId);
```